# Flutter 2 build project: Error: The method 'SpinKitPouringHourglass' isn't defined for the class '_LoadingIndicatorState'

Tags: flutter, build, build-error

I am trying to start my project with android studio but an error occurred whereas it was functionnal yesterday.

```
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_easyloading-3.0.0/lib/src/widgets/indicator.dart:166:22: Error: The method 'SpinKitPouringHourglass' isn't defined for the class '_LoadingIndicatorState'.
 - '_LoadingIndicatorState' is from 'package:flutter_easyloading/src/widgets/indicator.dart' ('/C:/Users/[MYUSER]/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_easyloading-3.0.0/lib/src/widgets/indicator.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SpinKitPouringHourglass'.
        _indicator = SpinKitPouringHourglass(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\lib\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\lib\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What I have already done:
reinstalled flutter SDK
reinstalled Android Studio
flutter clean
remove the build folder
remove the pubseck.lock
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub outdated
flutter doctor:

```
C:\lib\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19042.1165], locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\lib\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (8 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\[MY_USER]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\[MY_USER]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.84

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

What should I do to fix this error ?

Comment: try to set your java path correctly because your flutter doctor gives the problem **Unable to determine bundled Java version.**

Comment: It is already set up: jdk1.8.0_291 (In Project Structure > SDKs > JDK home path)

Comment: can you add your code snippet

Comment: No I can't it is a big project with multiple files and I guess it is not coming from files because I checkout on a commit of yesterday to be sure I hadn't added errors and it is still not working.
To add more information, this happened when I tried to add external icon to my project by using fluttericon.com (importing mine) However I deleted them and removed from the pubspec.yaml
An previously it was working without the "Unable to determine bundled Java version." (because I can't fix it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a method that does not exist with a plugin: flutter_easyloading.
Flutter easly loading is the problem.

good evening to you

Comment: Well, it is not completly true but I have just removed this package

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question too.
flutter_easyloading was working well before.
SO I find "import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';" in the indicator.dart in the flutter_easyloading 3.0.0.
BUT the flutter_spinkit has published a new version 5.1.0 and see the ChangeLog, I find the log "Renamed SpinKitPouringHourglass -> SpinKitPouringHourGlass for correctness".

YES, the flutter_easyloading MUST modify too for fixing this bug.

Comment: Yes true, flutter_easyloading has to upgrade his version so the problem can't be fixed yet. So from now just don't use this library. We should propose a fix on his git. You should use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit instead of the dumb library.